# Python script to read a line that has white space and return value

Tags: python, whitespace, readline

I need to read the line which has the  const keyword and return version as the value.

Content in the Version.php file

```
final class Version
{
    /**
     * The current Piwik version.
     * @var string
     */
    const VERSION = '2.0.3';
}
```

Here is the code I have written but its not returning anything. What I am doing wrong?

```
def piwik_check(module):
    dirs = ["/var/www/piwik/core"]
    for dir_name in dirs:
        if os.path.exists(dir_name):
            readme_file = open("%s/Version.php" % dir_name)
            for line in readme_file.xreadlines():
                if line.startswith(str.strip("const")):
                    #version = str(line)
                    version = str(line).split()[1].strip()
                    return {'version': version}
                    break
                else:
                   continue
                readme_file.close()
```

Comment: The line that begins with "const" has a leading white space/tab

Comment: `if line.startswith(str.strip("const")):` is a bit mixed up - it should be `if line.strip().startswith("const"):`, unless I'm mistaken. Voting for closure as being what seems to just be a typo to me. Also, remove the `else: continue` (it does nothing) and move `readme_file.close()` to be outside the `for` loop. Even better, use a `with` statement to automatically handle closing the file for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(infile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip().startswith("const"):
             print(line.split()[3].rstrip(";"))
'2.0.3'
```

In your function:

```
def piwik_check(module):
    dirs = ["/var/www/piwik/core"]
    for dir_name in dirs:
        if os.path.exists(dir_name):
            with open("{}/Version.php".format(dir_name)) as f:
                for line in f:
                    if line.strip().startswith("const"):
                        version = line.split()[3].rstrip(";")
                        return {"version":version}
```

`with` closes your files automatically,  the version number is the last/fourth element after splitting, if you just want the number rstrip the `;` and simply iterate over the file object `f`.

Comment: This did it. Thank you Padraic Cunningham.